# Importing CSV into MySQL through JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, csv

So I'm trying to import a CSV file into my MySQL database through my Java program. The program imports everything that's in the file, like it's suppose to, but the first row, it send to the end of the table, and the program see it's there, but if I search for that nr, it says it doesn't exists. And if I go directly to the database table and edit the nr(if the nr is 137, and I edit and write 137 again) the program recognize that nr, and if I search for it, it will find, and the database table organizes itself and sends that entry where is suppose to be.
I just don't see any logic in this. I someone could help me out, I'd appreciated.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\carla.DESKTOP-9364K9K\\Desktop\\Alunos_1.csv'
INTO TABLE utentes character set utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(NrProcesso, Nome, @Nome_Resumido, Ano, Turma, @Subsidio, @Nome_EE, @NIF, @email, @Obs)
SET 
Subsidio = IF(@Subsidio='','Nenhum',@Subsidio),
Nome_Resumido = IF(@Nome_Resumido='',NULL,@Nome_Resumido),
Nome_EE = IF(@Nome_EE='',NULL,@Nome_EE),
NIF = IF(@NIF = '', NULL,@NIF), 
email = IF(@email='',NULL,@email),
Obs = IF(@Obs='',NULL,@Obs);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show the code you're using in order for people to help you.

Comment: The problem is not in the code, if it was, the first row would be left out, and that's not the case, MySQL just don't recognize it, until it's edited

Answer (score 0):

You have do do something to check cell/column value and form a sql to inject in MySQL.

```
public List<Object> getRecordingsListFromCsv(String csvFileLocation, String mp3FileLocation, String mp3FileLocation2, String saveFileLocation, ChannelSftp sftp) {
        Map<String, File> recordingsFilesMap = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        List<String> errorFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> tempList = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            csvRows = 0;
            recordingsFilesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileLocation));
            String line = br.readLine();
            scriptLog.info("\n" + csvFileLocation + " loaded. Parsing File...");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] csvArray = parseCsvLineToArray(line);
//                System.out.println(Arrays.asList(csvArray) + "\n\n");
                if (csvArray[0].trim().isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Do your stuff here */

                csvRows++;

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            scriptLog.error("\n---ERROR---\n    FILE NOT FOUND: " + csvFileLocation);
            String errorStr = "Type=" + e.toString();
            errorStr += "StackTrace=" + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
            scriptLog.error(errorStr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String errorStr = "Type=" + e.toString();
            errorStr += "StackTrace=" + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
            scriptLog.error(errorStr);
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you at some extent!!